# Powershell to tally up departments in a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

To be honest up front I really have no idea how to start this but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a csv file that has a list of usernames. What I am trying to do it perform a lookup of the username, get the department and as I parse through the csv tally up the number of times it is found.

For example

```
Human resources 2
information Technology 5
```

As previously stated I am not sure how to even approach this other than I know I will need to parse the departments first then go into the number count.

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory

 Import-CSV "C:\Input.csv" | % {Get-ADUser $_.LoginID -Properties * | Select      -Property Department} | Export-CSV "C:\ADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of *.csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `Group-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group users by the `Department` attribute value:

```
Import-CSV "C:\Input.csv" |ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser $_.LoginID -Properties Department
} |Group-Object Department -NoElement |Select Name,Count |Export-Csv C:\output.csv
```

Comment: Interesting I have never heard of the "Group-Object" cmdlet I will give that a try.  Thanks